# Difference between Make Project, Make Module app, Build APK and Generate Signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio

What is the difference between `Make Project`, `Make Module app`, `Build APK` and `Generate Signed APK` options that you can find in menu bar->Build and when to use each one?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Make Project**: Means you create a real application which is working on a device 
    and has an executable file like an APK.

**Make Module**: Means you create a library project for you application which is executed with that project and has no executable file like an APK but has a `.jar`  file which works as a library.

**Build APK**: When you normally run your application, an APK file is generated locally which is like a ZIP file and is easily unzippable, no security is implemented, and you can get the code from that APK file. It is used basically for local testing.

**Signed APK**: It is that APK you can create with a password and security and it is not easily unzippable and is used for production.

Answer (score 7):

According to **IntelliJ :**

**Project:**

In the IntelliJ Platform, a project encapsulates all your source code, libraries, and build instructions into a single organizational unit. Everything you do using the IntelliJ Platform SDK is done within the context of a project. A project defines collections referred to as modules and libraries. Depending on the logical and functional requirements to the project, you can create a single-module or a multi-module project.

**Module:**

A module is a discrete unit of functionality that can be run, tested, and debugged independently. Modules includes such things as source code, build scripts, unit tests, deployment descriptors, etc. In the project, each module can use a specific SDK or inherit SDK defined on the project level (see the SDK section later in this document). A module can depend on other modules of the project.

**signed APK:**

signed packages to deploy and run your applications on physical devices. Based on this signature, the Android system identifies the author of every deployed application. You do not need to apply for a personal signature to any authority, a signature generated by IntelliJ IDEA is quite sufficient.

**Build APK:**

In debug mode, you sign your app with a debug certificate generated by the Android SDK tools. This certificate has a private key with a known password, so you can run and debug your app without typing the password every time you make a change to your project.

Android Studio signs your app in debug mode automatically when you run or debug your project from the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

**Make Project**:- Here Android studio consider this as workspace as in Eclipse. All modules which are required in application reside in project directory.

**Module** :- You make module when you want to create your own library. You can import module if you want to include library into your application where you can do changes as well. Other options are dependency or JAR file. But they are pre-compiled code and you can not do changes in that. Module allows you to made changes in code and compile when you run the application.

**Build APK** :- When we run the application then code gets compiled and APK file is generated. It is not secure it can be decompiled easily and anyone can get code from it. There are several ways to do so. So here comes Signed APK.

**Signed APK** :- Signed APK is necessary for uploading your apk to play store for security purpose. For building this you need to make it signed using **Keystore** and make that password protected. It assure you that your code is secure and hasn't tampered.

Answer (score 0):

Note: if U want to build debug or release output with sign key like "Generate Signed APK" command  and test it on emulatotor, add your sign key to build.gradle(app) like this:

```
signingConfigs {
release {
storeFile file("../key.jks")
storePassword "..."
keyAlias "..."
keyPassword "..."
}
}
buildTypes {
release {
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Note: Running your project with Shift+F10 automatically triggers an up-to-date build, so you don't need to execute **Make-Project** with Ctrl+F9 before launching with Shift+F10.

But if you just want the 'can it build?' check, and would like to AVOID the overhead of launching your app, Ctrl+F9 is useful.
(I arrived at this thread, to figure out if I had to do both C-F9 & S-F10 everytime.)

Comment: I can't see why this reply was marked as 'not useful'.
It answers the 'when to use' question, for 'Make Project', and shows a benefit of using Make-Project by itself, instead of doing a default build.